# htaccess clean url for the profile page

Tags: php, .htaccess

When I try to do this in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /includes/errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /includes/errors/403.php
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)$ /profile?user=$1
```

It works but the name I read is wrong.
When I do for example http://localhost/profile/Andre I get Andre.php as user and not Andre.
Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you rewrite according to your first rule, and since it is set as last, that's all that will happen. Try moving your profile rule above:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)$ /profile?user=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /includes/errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /includes/errors/403.php
```

I also added [NC,L] to mark the rule as **N**o**C**ase, and **L**ast